# Custom Keyboard Java - Potential InputMethod problem

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

One problem I had was that I created  a keyboard that even went as far as being successfully installed on my phone while in debugging, yet when I tried to select this specific keyboard, the app stopped working. I think it's something to do with InputMethod and the AndroidManifest, but I'm not completely sure. 
There is one yellow warning that tells me that MyInputMethodService has not been included in the AndroidManifest, yet when I look in that file, it is in the correct place, as far as I can tell. More detail of the code is below:

---

MyInputMethodService.java:
This also has the import statements above the included code.

public class MyInputMethodService extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

```
@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    KeyboardView keyboardView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_view, null);
    Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.number_pad);
    keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return keyboardView;
}
```

---

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.marcel54.keyboard3">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    android:fullBackupContent="true">
    <activity android:name="com.marcel54.keyboard3.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:label=".MyInputMethodService"
        android:name="com.marcel.keyboard.MyInputMethodService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.view.im"
            android:resource="@xml/method"/>
    </service>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Would this be stopping my keyboard from running once installed?

Comment: This is not a free coding service, and asking for libraries, off-site resources and stuff like it it's [off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185045/what-exactly-is-an-off-topic-question) here. Even if that wasn't a problem, you're not giving details of what kind of custom keyboard you want, if it's really a fully customized one, you're asking for too much.

But those problems you had with every keyboard you tried... we can help with that if you post the error and the code.

Comment: And why the tag javascript?